# (A + B + C) ≠ (A + C + B​) and compiler reordering

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, integer-overflow

Adding two 32-bit integers can result an integer overflow:

```
uint64_t u64_z = u32_x + u32_y;
```

This overflow can be avoided if one of the 32-bit integers is first casted or added to a 64-bit integer.

```
uint64_t u64_z = u32_x + u64_a + u32_y;
```

However, if the compiler decides to reorder the addition:

```
uint64_t u64_z = u32_x + u32_y + u64_a;
```

the integer overflow might still happen.

Are compilers allowed to do such a reordering or can we trust them to notice the result inconsistency and keep the expression order as is?

Comment: As far as I understand, since addition is left-associative the reordering in your example is not allowed.

Comment: You don't actually show integer overflow because you appear to be added `uint32_t` values - which don't overflow, they wrap.  These are not different behaviours.

Comment: See the section 1.9 of the c++ standards, it directly answers your question (there is even an example that is almost exactly the same as yours).

Comment: As @MartinBonner says, your examples don't show anything. Addition of unsigned values is done modulo, so such operations don't overflow (they wrap) are even commutative. There will be no difference what so ever if you reorder them, cast to `uint64_t` or things like that.

Comment: @rustyx, In your example if C is a 64-bit integer, A+(B+C) will not overflow. while (A+B)+C could overflow.

Comment: @Holt, the standard example is not mixing integers with different type size. I do agree the standard suggest reordering is OK as long as the result is consistent, I just wanted to assure compilers recognize possible integer overflow as an inconsistent result.

Comment: @Tal: As others already stated: there is no overflow of integers. Unsigned are defined to wrap, for signed it is undefined behaviour, so any implementation will do, including nasal daemons.

Comment: @Olaf, If I replace 'overflow' with 'wrap', someone else will tell us it might saturate - not wrap.

Comment: @Tal: Nonsense! As I already wrote: the standard is very clear and requires wrapping, not saturating (that would be possible with signed, as that is UB as-of the standard.

Comment: @Olaf, I've checked the standard, you are correct, wrapping is the correct wording to my question. Feel free to edit and correct the question.

Comment: @rustyx: Whether you *call* it wrapping or overflowing, the point remains that `((uint32_t)-1 + (uint32_t)1) + (uint64_t)0` results in `0`, whereas `(uint32_t)-1 + ((uint32_t)1 + (uint64_t)0)` results in `0x100000000`, and these two values are not equal. So it's significant whether or not the compiler can apply that transformation. But yeah, the standard only uses the word "overflow" for signed integers, not unsigned.

Comment: @Tal:  signed integers can overflow.  If they do so you have undefined behaviour, and it is the programmers responsibility to avoid it.  In practise, chips tend to wrap, or saturate, or raise a signal.  Compilers also use the fact that operations may not overflow to deduce something about the values involved.  *Unsigned* integers will always wrap (or you are not using a C or C++ compiler).

Comment: @Martin, Wikipedia suggest there were actual saturation-arithmetic C/C++ implementation, but I guess they do not confront to the standard.

Comment: Yes they did.  It is open to a compiler to extend the standard by (for example) defining the behaviour when integer arithmetic overflows.

Comment: @Tal: if you'd like a remark on the particular passage in WIkipedia that you're looking at then say exactly where it is or quote it. But there's no such thing as a C or C++ implementation in which *unsigned* arithmetic saturates. If it does that then it's not C and neither is it C++. Like there's no such thing as a 4-pointed "non-standard triangle". It's just not a triangle. Saturating *signed* arithmetic, sure.

Comment: Since when is wraparound not a form of overflow?

Comment: @Joren: in the context of C and C++, ever since the standard chose to use "overflow" as a jargon term with a more specific application. So, since 1989 not all wraparound is overflow ;-) In the context of signed arithmetic in C or C++, and in the context of the English language, sure, wraparound is one kind of overflow behaviour.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Interesting. What, then, does overflow mean in C++?

Comment: @Joren: it means the thing that happens when the mathematically-accurate result of a signed arithmetic (or floating-point IIRC) operation exceeds the limits of the type. It's basically a quirk of the standard, that it uses "overflow" to mean "danger, bad stuff!". It therefore doesn't apply it to unsigned arithmetic since that has a well-defined result within the limit of the type.

Comment: Parentheses are your friend...

Comment: @MartinBonner: Not only is it possible for compilers to define integer behaviors in case of overflow, but if the authors of the C89 rationale are to be believed, the decision to have short unsigned types promote to signed int was predicated at least in part on the fact that the majority of "current" C compilers did so in at least some cases [and the authors of the Standard likely intended that future C compilers for two's-complement hardware would continue to do likewise].

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If the optimiser does such a reordering it is still bound to the C specification, so such a reordering would become:

```
uint64_t u64_z = (uint64_t)u32_x + (uint64_t)u32_y + u64_a;
```

Rationale:

We start with

```
uint64_t u64_z = u32_x + u64_a + u32_y;
```

Addition is performed left-to-right.

The integer promotion rules state that in the first addition in the original expression, `u32_x` be promoted to `uint64_t`. In the second addition, `u32_y` will also be promoted to `uint64_t`.

So, in order to be compliant with the C specification, any optimiser must promote `u32_x` and `u32_y` to 64 bit unsigned values. This is equivalent to adding a cast. (The actual optimising is not done at the C level, but I use C notation because that is a notation that we understand.)

Comment: Isn't it left-associative, so `(u32_x + u32_t) + u64_a` ?

Comment: @Useless: Klas did cast everything to 64 bit. Now the order doesn't make any difference at all. The compiler doesn't need to follow associativity, it just has to produce the exact same result as if it did.

Comment: It seems to suggest that OP's code would be evaluated like that, which isn't true.

Comment: @Klas - care to explain *why* this is the case and *how* exactly you arrive at your code sample?

Comment: @rustyx It did need an explanation. Thanks for pushing me to add one.

Comment: The leftmost sub-expression is the addition of two `uint32_t`s. Why are they promoted?

Comment: @Useless The original expression is `uint64_t u64_z = u32_x + u64_a + u32_y;`

Comment: Ah, I focused on the last expression in the question - thanks.

Answer (score 29):

A compiler is only allowed to re-order under the *as if* rule.  That is, if the reordering will always give the same result as the specified ordering, then it is allowed.  Otherwise (as in your example), not.

For example, given the following expression

```
i32big1 - i32big2 + i32small
```

which has been carefully constructed to subtract the two values which are known to be large but similar, and only *then* add the other small value (thus avoiding any overflow), the compiler may choose to reorder into:

```
(i32small - i32big2) + i32big1
```

and rely on the fact that the target platform is using two-complement arithmetic with wrap-round to prevent problems.  (Such a reordering might be sensible if the compiler is pressed for registers, and happens to have `i32small` in a register already).

Comment: OP's example uses unsigned types. `i32big1 - i32big2 + i32small` implies signed types.  Additional concerns come into play.

Comment: @chux Absolutely.  The point I was trying to make is that although I could not write `(i32small-i32big2) + i32big1`, (because it might cause UB), the compiler can rearrange it to effectively that because the compiler can be confident that the behaviour will be correct.

Comment: @chux: Additional concerns like UB do not come into play, because we're talking about a compiler reordering under the as-if rule. A particular compiler may take advantage of knowing its own overflow behavior.

Answer (score 16):

There is the "as if" rule in C, C++, and Objective-C: The compiler may do whatever it likes as long as no conforming program can tell the difference.

In these languages, a + b + c is defined to be the same as (a + b) + c. If you can tell the difference between this and for example a + (b + c) then the compiler cannot change the order. If you can't tell the difference, then the compiler is free to change the order, but that's fine, because you can't tell the difference.

In your example, with b = 64 bit, a and c 32 bit, the compiler would be allowed to evaluate (b + a) + c or even (b + c) + a, because you couldn't tell the difference, but not (a + c) + b because you can tell the difference.

In other words, the compiler isn't allowed to do anything that makes your code behave different from what it should. It is not required to produce the code that you think it would produce, or that you think it should produce, but the code *will* give you exactly the results it should.

Comment: But with a big caveat; the compiler is free to assume no undefined behaviour (in this case overflow). This is similar to how an overflow check `if (a + 1 < a)` can be optimized out.

Comment: @csiz ...on _signed_ variables.  Unsigned variables have well-defined overflow semantics (wrap-around).

Answer (score 7):

Quoting from the [standards](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf):

> [ Note: Operators can be regrouped according to the usual
>   mathematical rules only where the operators really are associative or
>   commutative.7 For example, in the following fragment int a, b;
>
> ```
> /∗ ... ∗/
> a = a + 32760 + b + 5;
> ```
>
> the expression statement behaves exactly the same as
>
> ```
> a = (((a + 32760) + b) + 5);
> ```
>
> due to the associativity and precedence of these operators. Thus, the
>   result of the sum (a + 32760) is next added to b, and that result is
>   then added to 5 which results in the value assigned to a. On a machine
>   in which overflows produce an exception and in which the range of
>   values representable by an int is [-32768,+32767], the implementation
>   cannot rewrite this expression as
>
> ```
> a = ((a + b) + 32765);
> ```
>
> since if the values for a and b were, respectively, -32754 and -15,
>   the sum a + b would produce an exception while the original expression
>   would not; nor can the expression be rewritten either as
>
> ```
> a = ((a + 32765) + b);
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> a = (a + (b + 32765));
> ```
>
> since the values for a and b might have been, respectively, 4 and -8
>   or -17 and 12. However on a machine in which overflows do not produce
>   an exception and in which the results of overflows are reversible, the
>   above expression statement can be rewritten by the implementation in
>   any of the above ways because the same result will occur. — end note ]

Answer (score 4):

> Are compilers allowed to do such a reordering or can we trust them to notice the result inconsistency and keep the expression order as is?

The compiler can reorder only if it gives the same result - here, as you observed, it doesn't.

---

It's possible to write a function template, if you want one, which promotes all arguments to `std::common_type` before adding - this would be safe, and not rely on either argument order or manual casting, but it's pretty clunky.

Comment: I know explicit casting should be used, but I wish to know the compilers behavior when such casting was mistakenly omitted.

Comment: As I said, without explicit casting: the left addition is performed first, without integral promotion, and therefore subject to wrapping. The _result_ of that addition, possibly wrapped, is _then_ promoted to `uint64_t` for addition to the right-most value.

Comment: Your explanation about the as-if rule is totally wrong. The C language for example specifies what operations should happen on an abstract machine. The "as-if" rule allows it to do absolutely whatever it wants as long as nobody can tell the difference.

Comment: Which means the compiler can do whatever it wants so long as the result is the same as that determined by the left-associativity and arithmetic conversion rules shown.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on bit width of `unsigned/int`.

The below 2 are not the same (when `unsigned <= 32` bits).  `u32_x + u32_y` becomes 0.

```
u64_a = 0; u32_x = 1; u32_y = 0xFFFFFFFF;
uint64_t u64_z = u32_x + u64_a + u32_y;
uint64_t u64_z = u32_x + u32_y + u64_a;  // u32_x + u32_y carry does not add to sum.
```

They are the same (when `unsigned >= 34` bits).  Integer promotions caused  `u32_x + u32_y` addition to occur at 64-bit math.  Order is irrelevant.

It is UB (when `unsigned == 33` bits).  Integer promotions caused addition to occur at signed 33-bit math and signed overflow is UB.

> Are compilers allowed to do such a reordering ...?

(32 bit math): Re-order yes, but same results must occur, so not *that* re-ordering OP proposes.  Below are the same

```
// Same
u32_x + u64_a + u32_y;
u64_a + u32_x + u32_y;
u32_x + (uint64_t) u32_y + u64_a;
...

// Same as each other below, but not the same as the 3 above.
uint64_t u64_z = u32_x + u32_y + u64_a;
uint64_t u64_z = u64_a + (u32_x + u32_y);
```

> ...  can we trust them to notice the result inconsistency and keep the expression order as is?

Trust yes, but OP's coding goal is not crystal clear.  Should `u32_x + u32_y` carry contribute?  If OP wants that contribution, code should be

```
uint64_t u64_z = u64_a + u32_x + u32_y;
uint64_t u64_z = u32_x + u64_a + u32_y;
uint64_t u64_z = u32_x + (u32_y + u64_a);
```

But not

```
uint64_t u64_z = u32_x + u32_y + u64_a;
```